# HE!P!!! How do I make a method that iterates through list and checks type to print based on the type

Tags: python, list, loops, methods, types

I want to make a method(showList) that iterates through a list called dictionary and based on the type of object it prints either student, faculty, or both. the parameters needs to be s(for students), f(for faculty), and b(for both) and b needs to be default parameter for method. The object types are either Student or Faculty based on classes I made. Does this work?

```
def showList(b, s, f):
        for i in self.directory:
                    if isinstance (s, Student):
                        return True, "Student"
                    elif isinstance (f, Faculty):
                        return True, "Faculty"
                    elif isinstance (b, b):
                        return True, "Both"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only `return` once from a given function.  Since you said you want to `print` a string for each item in `self.directory` based on the type of the item, I think what you might want to do is:

```
def showList():
    for i in self.directory:
        if isinstance(i, Student) and isinstance(i, Faculty):
            print("Both")
        elif isinstance(i, Student):
            print("Student")
        elif isinstance (i, Faculty):
            print("Faculty")
```

However, a simpler approach yet might be to implement a `__str__` method in your various classes that will print the appropriate string when an instance of that class is printed.

Comment: This wont work as I need the parameters that I have stated above

Comment: The parameters in your original code don’t make any sense in the context of what the function is supposed to do.  The problem might make more sense if you gave an example of what those arguments might be and what the result would be.